# ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

tengo un problema que sinceramente no puedo resolver. Tengo una BD en Firebase de la que enviaba y recibia informacion sin mayor problema. Sin embargo, cuando pase mi aplicacion a produccion comence a recibir el siguiente error:

```
core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

    at SectorService.crearArreglo (sector.service.ts:73)

    at MapSubscriber.project (sector.service.ts:66)
```

Busco y busco y no puedo encontrar el problema. mi código es el siguiente

```
   getSectores(){
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/documentacion.json`)
        .pipe( map (resp => this.crearArreglo( resp )) );
    }


    private crearArreglo(sectorObj: object,){

        const sector: sectorModel[] = [];
        console.log(sectorObj);
        Object.keys(sectorObj).forEach ( key => {
            const sectores: sectorModel = sectorObj[key];
            sectores.id = key;

            sector.push( sectores );
        });
        return sector;

    }
```

Comment: A juzgar por lo que dices de que "funcionaba sin problema en pruebas pero ahora no en produccion", se me ocurre que si no haz modificado nada y estas intentadolo tal cual entonces el problema puede ser firebase y la base de datos (los permisos, la forma en la que accedes a la base de datos en produccion, etc), es decir, puede que el codigo no sea el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias! tenia mal un comando en el form que enviaba a firebase. Llamaba a una funcion que daba como resultado null en ID y todo lo que venia atras dejaba de funcionar!

Answer (score 0):

Este error se produce cuando llama a una función que espera un Objeto como argumento, pero en su lugar pasa indefinido o nulo.

Como eso suele ser por error, la solución es verificar el código y corregir la condición nula / indefinida para que la función obtenga un Objeto adecuado o no se llame en absoluto.

la solución seria esta:

```
private crearArreglo(sectorObj: object){
const sector: sectorModel[] = [];
console.log(sectorObj);
if(sectorObj === null){
return []
}
else{
Object.keys(sectorObj).forEach ( key => {
const sectores: sectorModel = sectorObj[key];
sectores.id = key;
sector.push( sectores );
});
}
return sector;
}
```